# Cannot login to SQL with active directory or SQL authentication

Tags: sql

Im installing SQL reporting services. After installation, the databases was created correctly and have the user permissions assigned.
A login domain\reportaccount is also created.
The problem is when i try to connect from visual studio, i want use the same account, but when i try it a have problems with different kind of authentication:

**Windows authetication**, no account selected > its OK, its using my account logged into the server.

**SQL authentication** > domain\reportaccount > Login failed for user 'domain\reportaccount' (if i use my account it also fail)

**Active Directoy Password Authentication** > domain\reportaccount > Login failed for user ".  (if i use my account it also fail)

**Active Directoy integrated Authentication**, no account selected > Its OK

**Active Directoy interactive Authentication**, domain\reportaccount > does not ask for a password

I guess i should use SQL authentication or Active Directoy integrated Authentication.

My question is, why fails if there is a login created and the corrects permissions in the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I googled "Active Directoy Password Authentication" as I have never heard of it. Nothing came up, but what did come up is:

"**Azure** Active Directoy Password Authentication"

So, are these typos? I am going to run under the assumption that they are and explain them all:

**Windows authetication** - this works because the account you are logged into the machine as has access.

**SQL authentication** - This is very common misconception. Because you are asked to provide a username and password, most people think they can type in their Windows accounts here, but it is not how it works. SQL has it's own INTERNAL user database, and when you use SQL auth, it looks for the user in SQL itself, not AD. You won't have any users created in there yet. As an example, have a look around in SQL Studio for "users", you will then be able to create a an **SQL** "user" there. It is this user you must userin when using this type of auth. Windows or AD account WILL NOT WORK.

***Azure* Active Directoy Password Authentication** - Azure AD is not the same as normal AD. It has it's own AD users (which is not the same as the ones you have on your local AD). MIcrosoft is in the process of renaming "Azure AD" to Azure Entra" because of all the confusion it causes by people thinking it is the same as a local AD, it is not.

Same goes for the other methods which I assume all have Azure in front of them (from what I read on the net just now)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Windows Authentication (basically automatic when logging into windows) then there are trust relationships between both your computer in Active Directory, and your user account in Active Directory once logged in.

I don't think you'll have any success using other Windows credentials while logged in under your user account, at least not from a MS product. As you will find when authorizing other users to see your reports, Edge, IE, and other MS products automatically "know" the logged-in user, and this info decides which assets they have access to, as well as what permissions they have with these assets.

To access SSRS (reporting services) via Visual Studio you can login to your computer using the domain\reportacct account, or setup a new login under Security in SQL Server Management Studio with adequate permissions, then switch Visual Studio to SQL Server authentication and use the login you've created.